# React ancor doesen't scroll down on reload

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-router

Im using React v6 and trying to implement ancors. I want that i can get the link of a subtitle so that when i send it to a friend the page is opend and scrolled down to the subtitle. I found out that Ancors are used for that but couldnt find a solution that works. When I navigate on the page via the link it works and it scrolls to the subtitle but if i close the tab and open it again this time with the link and the ancor it doesent scroll down.

[image]

does someone know an easy solution for this problem?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please paste your code as text, and not as an image.  You can use code fences `\`\`\`` around your code to make a block.

Comment: please do not use images when you can write code

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```js
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function ContentContainer({ header, content, descriptionExample, additiv, linkToSite, linkText }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      // Check if the current URL has a hash
      if (window.location.hash) {
        // Get the element with the corresponding id
        const element = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
        if (element) {
          // Scroll to the element
          element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
        }
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div id={header} className={style['content-container']}>
      <div onClick={() => iconClicked(header)} className={style['content-container-header']}>
        <Link smooth to={header}>{header}</Link>
        <div className={style['header-anker-icon']}>
          <InsertLinkOutlinedIcon className={style['link-icon']} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={style['content-container-content']}>{content}</div>
      <img className={style['content-container-img-example']} src={example} />
      <div className={style['content-container-description']}>{descriptionExample}</div>
      <div className={style['content-container-additiv']}>{additiv}</div>
      <a className={style['content-container-link']} href={linkToSite}>
        {linkText}
        <InsertLinkOutlinedIcon className={style['link-icon']} />
      </a>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ContentContainer;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.